# Adding ICollection in Linq using three models

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have entities for three tables the classes are

```
 public partial class pro_type
    {
        public pro_type()
        {
            this.pro = new HashSet<pro>();
        }

        public int pro_id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }    
        public virtual ICollection<pro> pro { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class pro
    {
        public pro()
        {
            this.project_discussion = new HashSet<p_dis>();
        }

        public int pro_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ts { get; set; }
        public int p_type_id { get; set; }  
        public virtual ICollection<p_disc> p_disc { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<p_type> p_type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And

```
  public partial class p_dis
    {
        public int p_disc_id { get; set; }
        public int pro_id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }      
        public virtual pro pro { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have following linq statement creating an object out of these three classes.

```
  var pView= (from c in db.p_disc
                               select new pView
                               {
                                 name=c.pro.name,
                                 pro_id=c.pro.pro_id,                           
                                 message=c.message,
                                 pro_type=typeof(ICollection<c.pro.p_type>)
                               }).Take(7);
            return pView;
```

I keep getting intellisense at pro_type=typeof(ICollection) saying..
"cannot implicitly convert type system.Type to system.collections.generic.icollection"

Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty obvious.

typeof(ICollection) does not create an ICollection<> - it gives you a System.Type object that has the details of your type.

MSDN for the System.Type class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx